# Converting shapefile to raster and extracting coordinates of each pixel

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, coordinates, astar

I currently have an EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 MultiPolygon shape in QGIS.

[image: Shapefile of lake]

I need to make a path planning tool to cross the lake above. In which case I need to convert this shapefile into a raster (from which I can make black and white 1 - lake, 0 - not lake), but I also need the lat / lon coordinates of each pixel, so that I can set the waypoints that the path planner finds.

How can I generate three arrays:

1. Boolean 1/0 for each pixel deciding whether it is water or not.
2. Matrix containing the latitudes of each pixel.
3. Matrix containing the longitudes of each pixel.

Comment: Coordinate x,y is implicit in a 2D raster. The seems like an XY Problem, since your question doesn't seem to get you closer to solving the goal.

Comment: If you are familiar with GDAL/OGR, try the `gdal_rasterize` program. I do not have a working code to share but have tested it in command line. You can create a GeoTIFF file and save lat/lon from GeoTIFF in separate files if you need. The description is available here: [https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html][1]

Alternatively, if you are already using QGIS, it has GDAL/OGR included in it - so you need to figure out how you can use `gdal_rasterize` from QGIS.

Or, use Python, import GDAL/OGR and use the `gdal_rasterize` module.

  [1]: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_rasterize.html

Comment: Rasterize it, read the raster into numpy array, calculate lat and longs